# Registered event onunload is not triggered when updating window

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have the following code that is already working:

```
popups[uuid] = window.open(url, popupConf[type].target, popupConf[type].string);
popups[uuid].focus();
$(popups[uuid]).load(function() {
    $(popups[uuid]).unload(function() {
        Stream.video.stop(uuid);
    });
});
```

I have it on a function `Stream.video.play(url, popupConf);` that I invoke with events on some links. Everything works fine, but the problem is that if I make this:

```
Stream.video.play('a',{ /* conf */});
```

And then

```
Stream.video.play('a',{ /* conf */});
```

Again, it does not work as it should... It only executes once the event unload...

Both executions of the code has the same target, so the window update as it should. This is important since I register other things once the window is open, and those should be unregistered once the window is unloaded (that is, closed or the data inside it changes).

**EDIT 1: This is the problem I have:**

```
<a id="click">Click me</a><br />
<a id="otherClick">Click me</a>

$(function() {
    var myWindow;
    $('#click, #otherClick').click(function() {
        myWindow = window.open("about:blank","test","resizable=0,location=0,toolbar=0,height=150,width=150");
        $(myWindow).load(function() {
            $(myWindow).unload(function() {
                alert("closed");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sd8wt/

Comment: Your two *this... and then* statements are the same?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yeap, with the exception that internally the uuid created is different. But that should work the same if the button clicked is the same or if it is other... the problem is that the event is not executed twice. That is: once I click the second link (or execute the second line - the "then" line -) the unload event is triggered, but once I close that window, the second event is not triggered...

Comment: @JaredFarrish See my update: http://jsfiddle.net/Sd8wt/

Comment: So in other words, when you click the first link, leave the window open, and click the second link, no `unload` fires unless the window itself closes?

Comment: @JaredFarrish The problem is that it does not fire when it is closed... Do you check my example? Follow this steps: Click on the first link, click on the second link (it will trigger the `onunload` event), click again in any link or close the window, it should trigger again the same event, but it is not happening...

Comment: Of course I looked at it. You would perhaps be better off reaching into the window (if it already exists) and run an event before opening the next video, e.g., combine `$.one()` with `$.contents()` perhaps (although that might only be necessary with `iframe`s) and call your video unloading script directly. `window.unload` isn't a very friendly event as it is. Just curious, why aren't you running the video(s) from within a modal in the same window?

Comment: Cause it will need to be placed in other monitor, so it should be in a different window... I'll try your suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Another approach could be to [`$.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the previous event before setting another. And the idea behind using `$.one()` is so that it doesn't get called more than once, of course.